# Как изменить иконку при клике на блок

Tags: javascript, html

При переключении вкладок должна меняться иконка слева от вкладки, для каждой вкладки своя иконка. Т.е. сейчас я поставил на тег `<i></i>` псевдоэлемент (иконка слева от вкладки), при переходе на активную вкладку иконка должна измениться на активную.

Как это сделать?

PS вкладки переключаются все норм, при переключении к `<li>` добавляется класс active.

```css
.new-ico-4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3NzctNzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3NzU3Nzc3NTc3N//AABEIAB4AHgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAXAAEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHBQQG/8QALRAAAQMCBAUDAwUAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAURABIhMQYHQVFhEyIjcYGRMkKhsfD/xAAXAQADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMB/8QAHBEAAgMAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQMAAhIRITIi/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwBdrlfp9CaC6g6pJUhS0JSkkqy726deuAOt8cVyrVRcpiVJjtrI9NhlwC3bTX8YZ+OIrFVVS6PJbJbmPOfIP25W1aEeb+MHnDcOVwzJqkKHJo65rK0pbU/fO6STcX3ACRva1ziLrmg5l0rFzwJm4T5kSqZMQzWZDq2VkZlOp9yR9hZQ/kW6jTDVS6lFqkREmG4FtqHfUeDge5hUtyoU6lOS0wk1l1z0/gNm1pPRRA0tob/XFnkc4tcOUFKWQlCRlJuE+46D/dcYlmhBq8y5zDqZpFQo83NYMokrGlxmKUpSfysYOeHOKocSbIkT/XW+97S4kmx7km+ovrYpOLXNWO6eKYTUmQtUeQpBUka2bzD2gfUE+cYJdBoL8hQbjutIAJTkFjYEed8K0a6MddsD5mKq1d2pTYqILPqIbWC20lWq0bnMNtf6H2wvcIVGnTIqmYMMQ1sgZ2ha1j1BG4wdU2PQqZ8rTMm2X9BANjvmzXuT22Ax2fLtp99uTVXihKJNksso19Nsai5tqo3JJ7nAjkHIHUZ+TXVvRn//2Q==) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  top: 35%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs block-2" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#settings-1" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-4"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#home-1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-1"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#profile-1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-2"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#messages-1" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-3"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .active:before - ваши правила для ".new-ico-4:before {"

Comment: Не совсем понятно за чем тут использовать `псевдо-элемент`...   Покажи свой `JS` ты `класс active` добавляешь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно создать отдельный класс для актив элемента

```
.new-ico-1:before {
  ...
}
.new-ico-2:before {
  ...
}
.new-ico-3:before {
  ...
}
.new-ico-4:before {
  ...
}
.nav li.active i:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  top: 35%;
}
```

Пример кода

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  a[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var active = document.querySelector('ul.nav li.active');
    active.classList.remove('active');
    if (!active.getAttribute('class')) {
      active.removeAttribute('class');
    }
    var li = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    li.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.nav li i {
  position: relative;
  
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 20px;
}

.nav li i.new-ico-1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav li i.new-ico-2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav li i.new-ico-3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav li i.new-ico-4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav li.active i:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  transform: rotate(0);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs block-2" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#settings-1" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-4"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#home-1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-1"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#profile-1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-2"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#messages-1" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="new-ico-3"></i>
      <span>Вкладка 4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В принципе именно то, что нужно. Но стало немного некорректно работать. При нажатии на вкладку должно меняться содержимое блока. При нажатии конкретно на текст иконки срабатывают, но содержимое блока не меняется, при нажатии рядом с текстом содержимое блока меняется и все срабатывает.

Comment: @Дмитрий дайте все коды на https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, с остальным разобрался очень помог ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий всегда пожалуйста